# How to add functions to buttons in an Android layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How to reference a function in a java Activity file to a xml layout file in AIDE?

Comment: please post your code whatever have you try ?

Comment: '<Button
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used AIDE myself, but I assume you are still able to edit the xml and java code? Write your function in java (suppose it is called `doSomething`), then call it when the button is clicked on. You can accomplish this two different ways.

1) Hook it up via xml

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:onClick="doSomething"/>
```

2) Hook it up via java

```
Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of functions which a `Button` can perform. For example, one function is the `OnClick`event that fires when you click the button.

In order to wire up the event, you must do the following:

Within the XML file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Class level:

```
Button mButton;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
mButton = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Logic goes here
             }
});
```